# Report on Activities on Converted Leads

Tags: reporting, lead-conversion, activities, bug

We need a report to show all Activities on a Lead before it was converted. Is it possible to do it?

As per the Salesforce help, Activities on Leads are moved to Account, Contacts and Opportunities where it is converted. (https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_leads_what_happens_when.htm&language=en_US) I have a parameter on Account that captures whether it was created via Lead Conversion or not. But I can't find only those activities that moved from Lead.

Also, I was able to see few Activities on Leads even after it has been converted. Is that a bug from Salesforce? Or is there another reason for it?